# solr - string search field multiple value, all word must match

Tags: solr

Currently i have sample data like this :

```
<doc>
<int name="name">Nice Dress</int>
<arr name="keyword">
  <str>best cocktail dress</str>
  <str>platform complete pumps</str>
  <str>platform pumps</str>
  <str>slip dress</str>
</arr>
```

I used multiple value for "keyword" field.

**case 1**

```
defType:edismax
qf:keyword
q:cocktail dress
```

solr will return the data.

**case 2**

```
defType:edismax
qf:keyword
q:coctail dress pump
```

it still return the data, If we see from the sample data, no keyword contain all this 3 word ('coctail' 'dress' 'pump') in one row of each keyword.
How to make solr not to return this result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for two parameters

`positionIncrementGap` - For multivalued fields this parameter would decide what is it distance between the two fields in the multivalued fields. If this value is 100 so the distance between the two multivalued fields would be 100 positions.

**Note** - The default positionIncrementGap is 0

Check for the `qs` [query slop](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qs_.28Query_Phrase_Slop.29) parameter for dismax which will will decide the slop match between the terms.

Comment: Thanks. it works.i increased the number become around 1000. 100, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
q:(coctail dress pump)~100
```

with your `positionIncrementGap` set to something like `300`.

Those values will need to change depending on how long are your data.